# How to add Http Header and body in Data field tag

Tags: docusignapi

I made a hyperlink button using Data Field tag which is available in standard tags. It is successfully navigating to a URL . Could I add a header and a body in data field tag? Like we add when we make an HTTP request using a programming language.

Comment: How exactly did you make a hyperlink button through a Data Field tag?  I tried doing the same by putting `https://www.google.com` into a Data Field and it just shows up as text in my test, not a clickable hyperlink.  Was there a trick you did to get that to work?

Comment: Please see this link. https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/docusign-tags/docusign-tags#DataField

Comment: Per the documentation provided, i agree the answer is no. The best you can do is pass variables in the URL and parse them up on the receiving pages side.